# Powershell if statement into foreach loop from csv

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, foreach

I have created a script to go through a csv file and take the values of each column. Based on one of the values an if statement must be ran and bring back the results. So far it only goes through the if, not the else. Can you help me figure this out? This is the code I have.

```
$members = import-csv membership.csv
select-object "id","group","operation" |


Foreach ($row in $members) {
    If ($row.operation = "add")

    {write-host "This is IF statement"}

    Else 

    {write-host "This is ELSE statement"}
}
```

Comment: Maybe [`If ($row.operation -eq "add")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators)?

Comment: Remove the `|` from the end of the `Select-Object` command because you are not sending that pipeline data anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$members = import-csv membership.csv
select-object "id","group","operation" |


Foreach ($row in $members) {
If ($row.operation -eq "add")

{write-host "This is IF statement"}

Else 

{write-host "This is ELSE statement"}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to remove the `|` ;)

Comment: Thank you very much all, I removed the pipe and changed the = to -eq and now it works.